# RecyclerView shows wrong element on item insert

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm writing a hierarchical RecyclerView and everything is well, except when I expand one of the elements the last view is wrongly drawn. when I scroll up and down it disappeas and shows the right one:
[When clicked to expand the element:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHkt9.jpg)
[After a small scrolling:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNddJ.jpg)
[After scrolling up and down the issue gets solved and the view is drawn well!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmTY0.jpg)
Another example:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srn5r.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7UHF.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqkwF.jpg)
Here is my recyclerAdapter code:

```
public class AdapterForRecyclerViewInPage2to4Last  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForRecyclerViewInPage2to4Last.RecyclerviewViewHolder>{
private Context mContext;

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

public AdapterForRecyclerViewInPage2to4Last(Context pContext, ...) {
   ...
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterForRecyclerViewInPage2to4Last.RecyclerviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expansion_element_last, parent, false);
    return new AdapterForRecyclerViewInPage2to4Last.RecyclerviewViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdapterForRecyclerViewInPage2to4Last.RecyclerviewViewHolder pholder, final int position) {
    //...
    //Adding items when clicked
    notifyItemRangeInserted(...);
    //Removing items when clicked
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(...);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return elementObjectsLive.size();
}

class RecyclerviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
    RecyclerviewViewHolder(View pView1) {
        super(pView1);
        ...
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused when layout inflation is not done properly.Check that all views are inflated correctly in adapter.

Comment: I checked this and malso added override methods but didn't help. All views get wrongly displayed when in bottom of the recyclerview and are displayed right when shown again. can't see further error when inflating.